# Google Spreadsheet Re order Columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'll explain an example of the situation before I ask the question.

If I have a pile of 5 numbered boxes and I scan them into a spreadsheet in the following order. 4,2,3,5,1

I copy that list into another program which adds more info to each number (which is what I want) but messes up the order. So now it is 3A,4D,1C,2B,5E.

Is there a formula I can use to reorder my new list to the original?  I want to keep the original order as I print labels for these boxes and this would keep the order, meaning ordering both numerically won't work.

Thanks,
Graeme

Comment: Considering we don't know what this "other program" is doing or the mechanisms you're using to transfer back and forth, there's not an obvious answer. Can your 2nd program take reference values, such that you can carry an extra value/column to indicate an ordering property when that 2nd program produces output?

Comment: Essentially I'm just copying and pasting the lists between programs.  Also,  there's no way of having the "other program"as we'll call it to reorder the numbers as you put them it.  Sorry to be incredibly vague about this.

Also the other program is essentially for stock taking, so it can only take one column at a time.  However, it can produce multiple columns in the results; i.e UPC, product description, date received etc.

Comment: Please don't add the Excel tag to Google Spreadsheet questions - they're not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend an HLookup.  Look for the character in your original list and add "*" which is a wild card for the second character.

Assumptions:

- The first character is unique in the set.
- Each value is in its own cell.
- The original list is retained after intermediate program runs.

[image: HLookup in Google Sheets]